# How do I scope or partition 1 big Javascript file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

this applies to all server/client-side web application but I like to know it for either rails or asp.net.

A good practise is to have 1 big application.js file with all my JavaScript. So when I have multiple pages or actions how can I scope the javascript.

For example I have a login page and customer entry form.

On the login page I would like to set the focus on the username on `document.ready` and in the customer entry form I would like to set `focus` on the textbox of the first name, do some heavy Ajax and client-side validation. How can I make sure that the scripts do not collide and scope them properly?

Both parts of the script exist in one file so how do I access the right portion of script at the right time?

Are there any best practise recommendations? I do not want to load a separate file for individual controller actions...

Any help would be fantastic...

Comment: I am guessing its scalability vs. little performance gain here.

Comment: Why is it good practice to have 1 big application.js with all your Javascript?

Comment: In general, I like to use the "revealing module pattern" that allows me to scope my modules and keep variables private. I am also able to separate the code into different files based on the module. For common files, I set them up into bundles so that all the JS is included in one file and minified.

Comment: Have you succeeded in organizing your code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered doing a location check in javascript?

Something like...

```
if(location.href.match(/login\.aspx/)){
    //code here
} else if(location.href.match(/otherpage\.aspx/)){
    //other code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Executing only specific part of the code**

I have faced a similar problem but not in rails but asp.net.

This javascript solution should work anywhere:

http://paulirish.com/2009/markup-based-unobtrusive-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution/

This is basically the mother of DOM-based routing. You give attributes to the body tag that specifies where you are. Read through it, it's pretty simple, and functional.

DOM-based routing is very popular nowadays and have been implemented in a lot of frameworks (I'm pretty sure rails have it's own solution for this), but this simple version can be implemented anywhere easily.

Also there are a few followup links in that post, you should read them also and decide what is the best for you.

**Bundling scripts**

It is a misconception that "what you write/debug is what you publish" in JavaScript:

Since it is a script language interpreted on the client side, you can send it directly through the net without any processing, but it results in needlessly large files and a lot of separate requests: one for each file. Therefore you can remove all the comments/spaces from it and bump all your code into one file, but it results in unmaintainable code. You may think that is a necessary tradeoff but it is not!

You can "build" the javascript files that bundles them together, and minifies their content to a much smaller size. There are a lot of tools for it, I'm sure rails have it's own solution (search for bundling javascript on your favorite search provider). You can use the unbundled/unminified code in your test environment, so it is very easy to develop and debug. When you need to publish it to a production environment you bundle your scripts.

You can then define the objects/functions in different files like:

file1:

```
var FOO = {

};
```

file2:

```
FOO.common = {
  init     : function(){ ... },
  finalize : function(){ ... }  
};
```

file3:

```
FOO.shopping = {
  init     : function(){ ... },
  cart     : function(){ ... },
  category : function(){ ... }
};
```

This way you basically have the same result as you would in 1 file, but also it's a little clearer to read while designing the app.

EDIT: this solution is using jQuery's `$(document).ready()` function. If this is undesirable you could also hook it up to any other ready event.